# Controlling .animate() properties with .mousedown()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
$launch.click(function launch() {
    if(!counter) counter = setInterval(startClock, 1000);
    $ball.mousedown().animate({ left: '100%' }, {
      progress: checkCollision,
      duration: 750,
      easing: 'linear',
      complete: resetBall
    });
  });
```

where a ball is being shot across the screen using the property .animate(); I am looking to change the speed of the ball depending on how long you have the mouse clicked down.

Many thanks to any contributions.

First post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You to need to detect how mouse down for the desired element, you can use something like this :

```
var start,end;

$launch.mousedown(function(){
  start = new Date();
});

$launch.mouseup(function(){
  end = new Date();
});

$launch.click(function launch() {
  var duration = end  - start;//difference in milliseconds
  if(!counter) counter = setInterval(startClock, 1000);
    $ball.mousedown().animate({ left: '100%' }, {
      progress: checkCollision,
      duration: duration ,
      easing: 'linear',
      complete: resetBall
    });
});
```